# Steam Install Problems

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, dependencies, steam

No matter how many times I try, I just CANNOT install steam. I've tried installing, uninstalling, installing random dependencies, typing all kinds of commands in the terminal, and even using Wine to get it... it just DOES NOT work. It's a different problem each time. One time it said something about a trackpad (even though i wasn't using any trackpad), the other was about dependencies, and another simply just said "couldn't load steam.. contact tech support" without telling me what's wrong. This is making me really really mad. I really want to play my games!!!!

Comment: What is your question.  I realise that you are frustrated, but we can not help you.  Can you do a fresh install?  Start from the very beginning, how are you installing Steam?  Can you do it from a command-line / terminal window?  What set of instructions are you following?  https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how+to+install+steam+ubuntu+16.04&oq=how+to+install+steam+ubuntu+16.04&aqs=chrome..69i57.10307j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8  https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-steam-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

run following command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386
```

Than try installing steam. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I found the solution. Turns out there's a specific .so.6 file i'm supposed to delete. After deleting this file, Steam started up just fine. Thanks for all your suggestions, but i got it working by myself. Thank you!